# While Statement(no result in shell)

Tags: python, while-loop

My program should print the sum from even numbers from 2 to 10, but when I pass even_while() in the shell I don't see any result. Which is the problem?

```
def even_while():


    number = 2
    s = 0

    while number < 10:
        if number % 2 == 0:
            old_number = number
            number = number + 1
            s = s + old_number

    print(s)
```

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by 'in the shell'?  If you run Python interactively, copy/paste the code shown, and then invoke `even_while()`, it should run...badly because of the bugs, but it should run. If you save that in `evenwhile.py` and run `python evenwhile.py`, then you haven't invoked the function (you'd need to add `even_while()` at the end). If you mean something else, you should say what. For debugging, why not put `print number, s` before the `if` statement; it'll tell you why you don't get what you think you should be getting. Judicious printing of variables is a basic debugging technique.

Answer (score 5):

"Infinite loop".  `number` starts as 2.  That's even, so add 1 to it.  That leaves `number` as 3.  Now the `while` loop goes around "forever".  `number % 2 == 0` is never true (`number` is 3!), and `number` never changes again.

Answer (score 2):

You don't increment `number` unless `number % 2 == 0`, so the `while` loop doesn't make any progress.

Additionally, you might enjoy the `range` builtin:

```
def even_while():
    s = 0

    for number in range(2, 10):
        if number % 2 == 0:
            old_number = number
            s = s + old_number

    print(s)
```

Comment: If the answer needs to include 10, the range should be specified as 11, shouldn't it?  You could also use `range(2, 11, 2)` to get just the even numbers.  And you could use a list comprehension, I believe (working on the syntax now...).

Comment: By making full use of the two builtin functions `range` and `sum`, this can become an one-liner: `print(sum(range(2, 11, 2)))`.

Comment: Yah, I was going for a direct clone of the original. Really the *best* method is `numsteps = (stop - start) // step + 1; start * numsteps + (step*numsteps*(numsteps-1))//2` 'cause it's linear time.

Answer (score 0):

```
def even_while():

    number = 0
    s = 0

    while number < 11:
        number = number + 1
        if number % 2 == 0:
            old_number = number
            s = s + old_number

    print(s)
```

I think this is ok.

Comment: Whether it's OK depends on what you're trying to **accomplish**.  You haven't told us that.  At least it doesn't suffer from an infinite loop ;-)

Comment: FYI, you **could** write this as `print(sum(range(0, 11, 2)))`.  Just something to ponder ;-)